# How to reduce the sensitivity of the swipe?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

There is a slider. It has slides. Slides have buttons. If you try to quickly click on the buttons in different slides, you might accidentally move the slide a bit, which prevents the click from working (the slider will think that the user intended to swipe the slide, not to click on it).

Is there any way to decrease the sensitivity of the movement? For example, if the movement is less than 3px, it will be a click, not a swipe.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-navigation-forked-0xp1p4?file=/index.html

Comment: Whta kind of slider is it? An HTML input range slider ? A custom slider made through JS? Without code or examples how do you expect someone can even try to answer this question ?

Comment: @CesarePolonara, this is an html slider made with the Swiper.js library.

Comment: So why don't you attach the code of the slider?

Comment: @CesarePolonara https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-navigation-forked-0xp1p4?file=/index.html